# Is the bound $\Gamma(\alpha, x) \leq \tfrac{3}{2} e^{-x} (x + \alpha )^{\alpha - 1}$ valid for all $x > 0$ and $\alpha \geq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, gamma-function

Recall the incomplete Gamma function, which is defined as
$$
\Gamma(\alpha, x) = \int_x^\infty t^{\alpha - 1} e^{-t} \, dt.
$$

> My question is whether or not
> $$
> \Gamma(\alpha, x) \leq \frac{3}{2}(x + \alpha)^{\alpha - 1} e^{-x} 
> $$
> holds for all $x > 0$ and any $\alpha \geq 0 $.

Below, I prove it holds for all *integers* $\alpha \geq 0$.
Indeed, integration by parts gives
$$
\Gamma(\alpha, x) = x^{\alpha - 1} e^{-x} + (\alpha - 1)\Gamma(\alpha- 1, x). 
$$
In particular, using the fact that $\Gamma(1, x) = \int_x^\infty e^{-t} \, dt = e^{-x}$, it can be verified that for all integers $k \geq 0$, that
$$
e^x \Gamma(k + 1, x) = \sum_{j=0}^k x^k (k-j)! \binom{k}{j} \leq \sum_{j=0}^k x^k k^{k-j} \binom{k}{j} = (x + k)^k.
$$
Or stated otherwise, for all $x > 0$,
$$
\Gamma(\alpha, x) \leq e^{-x} (x + \alpha - 1)^{\alpha - 1} \leq \frac{3}{2} e^{-x} (x + \alpha)^{\alpha - 1} \quad \mbox{for any}~\alpha \in \{1, 2, 3, \dots\}.
$$
Moreover, the bound above can also trivially be verified at $\alpha = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Some thoughts.** (A rigorous proof for (1) and (2) is required.)

Let
$$F(x) := \frac{3}{2}(x + \alpha)^{\alpha - 1} \mathrm{e}^{-x} - \int_x^\infty t^{\alpha - 1} \mathrm{e}^{-t} \, \mathrm{d} t.$$
We have
\begin{align*}
 F'(x) &= -\frac32(x + \alpha)^{\alpha - 2}\mathrm{e}^{-x}(1 + x) + x^{\alpha - 1} \mathrm{e}^{- x}\\
 &= - \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-x} x^{\alpha}(1 + x)}{(x + \alpha)^2}\left( \frac32\left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{x}\right)^{\alpha} - \frac{(x+\alpha)^2}{x(1 + x)}\right).
\end{align*}

We split into three cases.

**Case 1.** $\alpha \ge 1$ and $x > 0$

By Bernoulli inequality,
we have
$$\frac32\left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{x}\right)^{\alpha} - \frac{(x+\alpha)^2}{x(1 + x)} \ge 1\cdot \left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{x}\cdot \alpha\right) - \frac{(x+\alpha)^2}{x(1 + x)}
= \frac{(\alpha - 1)^2}{1 + x}\ge 0.$$
Thus, $F'(x) \le 0$ on $(0, \infty)$.
Also, we have $F(\infty) = 0$.
Thus, $F(x) \ge 0$ for all $x > 0$.

**Case 2.** $0 \le \alpha < 1$ and $x > 1$

By Bernoulli inequality,
we have $$\left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{x}\right)^{\alpha} = \frac{\left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{x}\right)}{\left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{x}\right)^{1 - \alpha}} \ge \frac{\left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{x}\right)}{1 + \frac{\alpha}{x}\cdot (1 - \alpha)},$$
and
$$\frac32\left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{x}\right)^{\alpha} - \frac{(x+\alpha)^2}{x(1 + x)}
\ge \frac32 \cdot \frac{\left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{x}\right)}{1 + \frac{\alpha}{x}\cdot (1 - \alpha)} - \frac{(x+\alpha)^2}{x(1 + x)} \ge 0.$$
Thus, $F'(x) \le 0$ on $(1, \infty)$.
Also, we have $F(\infty) = 0$.
Thus, $F(x) \ge 0$ for all $x > 1$.

**Case 3.** $0 \le \alpha < 1$ and $0 < x \le 1$

Using $\mathrm{e}^{-t} \ge 1 - t$ and the Bernoulli inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 \int_x^\infty t^{\alpha - 1} \mathrm{e}^{-t} \, \mathrm{d} t
 &= \int_0^\infty t^{\alpha - 1} \mathrm{e}^{-t} \, \mathrm{d} t - \int_0^x t^{\alpha - 1} \mathrm{e}^{-t} \, \mathrm{d} t\\
 &\le \int_0^\infty t^{\alpha - 1} \mathrm{e}^{-t} \, \mathrm{d} t - \int_0^x t^{\alpha - 1} (1 - t) \, \mathrm{d} t\\
 &= \Gamma(\alpha) - \left( \frac{1}{\alpha} x^\alpha - \frac{1}{\alpha + 1}x^{\alpha + 1}\right)\\
 &= \Gamma(\alpha) - \frac{x}{x^{1 - \alpha}} \left(\frac{1}{\alpha} - \frac{x}{\alpha + 1}\right)\\
 &\le \Gamma(\alpha) - \frac{x}{1 + (x - 1)(1 - \alpha)} \left(\frac{1}{\alpha} - \frac{x}{\alpha + 1}\right).
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that
$$f(x) := \frac{3}{2}(x + \alpha)^{\alpha - 1} \mathrm{e}^{-x} - \Gamma(\alpha) + \frac{x}{1 + (x - 1)(1 - \alpha)} \left(\frac{1}{\alpha} - \frac{x}{\alpha + 1}\right) \ge 0.$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 f'(x) &= \frac{(1 - x)(1 + \alpha + x - \alpha x)}{(\alpha + 1)(\alpha + x - \alpha x)^2} - \frac32 (x + \alpha)^{\alpha - 2}\mathrm{e}^{-x}(1 + x)\\
 &\le \frac{(1 - x)(1 + \alpha + x - \alpha x)}{(\alpha + 1)(\alpha + x - \alpha x)^2} - \frac32 (x + \alpha)^{\alpha - 2}(1 - x)(1 + x)\\
 &= (1 - x)\left(\frac{1 + \alpha + x - \alpha x}{(\alpha + 1)(\alpha + x - \alpha x)^2} - \frac32 (x + \alpha)^{\alpha - 2}(1 + x)\right)\\
 &\le 0 \tag{1}
\end{align*}
where we use $\mathrm{e}^{-x} \ge 1 - x$.

Also, we have
$$f(1) = \frac32 (\alpha + 1)^{\alpha - 1}\mathrm{e}^{-1} - \Gamma(\alpha) + \frac{1}{\alpha} - \frac{1}{\alpha + 1} > 0. \tag{2}$$
Thus, $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $0 < x \le 1$.